# Is there a way to set prefetchSize for a queue dynamically with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a list of queues inside my `app.properties` like this:

```
queue.listener.names=queue0, queue1, queue2, queue3, queue4
queue.concurrency=1, 2, 3, 4, 5
queue.prefetchSize=1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

My task is to register all endpoints with the details of `app.properties` in ActiveMQ.

For now, my code goes like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MyClass implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

    @Value("${queue.listener.names}")
    private List<String> listeners;

    @Value("${queue.concurrency}")
    private String[] concurr;
    
    @Value("${queue.prefetchSize}")
    private String[] prefetchSize;

    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {

        listeners.forEach(listener -> {
            SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
            int index = listeners.indexOf(listener);
            endpoint.setId(listener);
            endpoint.setDestination(listener);
            endpoint.setConcurrency(concurr[index]);
            endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> {
                // do something
            });
            registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
            
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't find a way to set the prefetch size for each queue. I just get it for all queues by setting `prefetchSize` when I pass the broker url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html), prefetch size can be configured on a per-consumer basis by using a special syntax on the destination, e.g.:

```
TEST.QUEUE?consumer.prefetchSize=10
```

So in your `app.properties` you could use something like this:

```
queue.listener.names=queue0?consumer.prefetchSize=200, queue1?consumer.prefetchSize=100, queue2?consumer.prefetchSize=20, queue3?consumer.prefetchSize=10, queue4?consumer.prefetchSize=50
```

Comment: Can you please explain where exactly this configuration needs to be placed?
I mean - on Producer application.properties or consumer application.properties ?

Comment: The producer doesn't fetch any messages so setting the prefetchSize is meaningless there. It needs to be set on the consumer.